# How to plot function with positive constants and equality for x variable?

Tags: r, rstudio, constants, equality

I'm looking how to plot f(x) = (ax)/(k^2 + x^2).
I don't have a preference for units or large the graph is.

k and a are both positive constants

x ≥ 0.

Very rudimentary try at code:

```
eq = function(x){((ax)/((k^2)+(x^2))}   
plot(eq(1:1000), type='l')
```

Comment: you defined your `function` as a `function` of `x` in which you passed the values `1:1000`, but you are yet to determine what are the values for `a` and `k`. Are those constants as well?

Comment: The values of a and k are simply positive constants. No quantitative value is given to them. the function is in terms of x.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `k` and `a` are positive constants, I will try to rewrite your code. 
It would be either you define your `k` and `a` before or if you say it would be just constantly one number you may define them in the function as well.

```
eq <- function(x){
  a = 2
  k = 3
  (a*x)/(k^2)+(x^2)
}

plot(eq(1:1000), type="l")
```

If you want to define all your variables but still want the `a` and `k` with a default value of `2 and 3` respectively, you may write it as:

```
eq <- function(x, a=2, k=3){
  (a*x)/(k^2)+(x^2)
}

plot(eq(1:1000), type="l")
```

Comment: Thank you! With a little tweaking in regards to parenthesis and scaling the range to include 0 this did the trick! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aresyl Accept as answer?